# How to prove that an orthonormal matrix inverse's is its transpose?

Tags: linear-algebra

I saw a definition of an orthonormal matrix that says: "A squared matrix is orthonormal if its columns are orthonormal"
And from this definition, it says that A^-1=A^T.
Now. I understand that A's columns are independent and because it is a square matrix it's also invertible. And I also understand that A^T * A = I.
But to show that A^-1 = A^T we need to show that A * A^T = I also and I don't know how to prove it.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).